# Why the value in list stay the same?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Does lambda not change value when using `key=` in `sort()` function?

```
nas = [1,2,3,4,5]

nas.sort(key=lambda a: a + 1)
print(nas)
```

`nas` still has same value why didn't get 1 added using lambda?

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  That wouldn't be very useful.  You asked it to sort the list using a custom key function.  That key will result in the same order as the original key, so nothing changes.  Perhaps you wanted `nas = [a+1 for a in nas]`.

Comment: Sorting by `a+1` is the same as sorting by `a` and `nas` was already sorted.

Comment: Please explain why you **think** `nas` would change? Sorting with a key of `+1` *won't change the order*, since your list is already sorted, and adding 1 to integers doesn't change the way they will compare!

Comment: "Does lambda not change value when using key= in sort() function?" No, no it doesn't, why would it? That would defeat its purpose, which is to provide a key function to *sort the values in the list*.

Comment: As an aside, this has nothing to do with `lambda` expressions. Lambda expressions simply create function objects, the exact same sort of function objects as function definition statements.

Comment: Try it with `nas.sort(key=lambda a: 1/a)` instead if you want an example where the order of the list is actually modified.

Comment: So lambda does add 1 to each items and sorts but still prints the original?

Comment: Is there any video suggestions cause the answers here have left me even more confused? I appreciate the help but I still don't how key= works ?

Answer (score 0):

As the name might suggest, `sort` only ... `sorts`. It won't change any of the elements from the lambda you provide it. That lambda is only used to define how elements of your list should be sorted.

So for example, when trying to compare `3` and `4`, your lambda instructs it to compare `3` as if it were `4`, and `4` as if it were `5`. Of course, this would have the same impact of just comparing the integers directly:

```py
nas = [1,2,3,4,5]

nas.sort(key=lambda a: a + 1) # Or just `nas.sort()`
print(nas)
```

Comment: So where does those compared value of a being added 1 go?

Comment: @DuranDas Long term? Nowhere. Internally `sort` will call your lambda any time it needs to compare any pair of elements in your array. It'll use the results to decide how the two should be ordered relative to each other, then discard them. Imagine that rather than `a < b`, it checks `key(a) < key(b)`

Comment: I don't wanna waste your time too much but could you explain it little more using examples?

Comment: No problem at all. Start off by having a read through https://realpython.com/sorting-algorithms-python/ up to the bubble sort example. While bubble sort is a terrible sorting algorithm performance-wise, it's reasonably easy to intuit and implement. Like other comparison-based sorting algorithms (which is most of them), the final sort order of elements is determined by a sequence of comparisons of pairs of elements. For example, if I check that `a < b` and `b < c`, I know that I have to order `a` before `c` (without explicitly needing another check). f you're calling `sort` with a key lambda...

Comment: ... like this, it's as if you're changing the line `if array[j] > array[j + 1]:` with `if key(array[j]) > key(array[j + 1]):`. That is, rather comparing two elements themselves (`array[j]`, and `array[j + 1]`), they're compared by the result you get after running them through the lambda you provided. Let me know if you have questions or need me to clarify any parts